# Problems with checking for duplicate user in MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to check if the username already exists in the database, but I'm struggling with it. I get an error saying:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /var/www/public/firsttry/index.php
```

This is part of my code where I'm trying to implement this:

```
/*Check for duplicate in DB */
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM Users (username, password) WHERE username = ?");

    $stmt2->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $rows= mysqli_num_rows($stmt2);

    if($rows>=1){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This username is taken!')</script>";
    }
    else{
      /*Proceed*/
    }
```

As you can see first I write a prepared statement and try to bind a value into it which is `$username` `($_POST["username"])` is assigned to it. I execute the query and then I try to see how many affected rows are returned, if it is more or equal to 1, I throw an alert, else, user is able to register. 
Im pretty sure its just some small mistake, but I am kinda new to php so please bear with me. I am aware that my `SELECT` statement might return false, but why does it complain that I am trying to `bind_param` on boolean?

Comment: That's not a valid SELECT statement, so the prepare is failing.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you for a fast answer, maybe you could tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: I suspect every SQL tutorial out there shows the correct syntax for a basic SELECT statements, probably on their first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select query in:

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = ?");
```

And you should use an if statement to have a safe code:

```
if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = ?"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, and I closed the `if` statement after `if($rows>=1)` statement. I keep getting warning now, that `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`. For the sake of space, I uploaded my fixed part of the code [here](http://pastebin.com/6Lmwrmq9) . It doesn't allow to save duplicate tho, it works, although it doesn't throw this alert message I wrote and it shows that warning

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query fails so that `$stmt2` becomes `false`.

Please change your query to (remove the `(username, password)`):

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM Users WHERE username = ?");
```